# Map two lists into one single list of dictionaries

Tags: python, dictionary, list

Imagine I have these python lists:

```
keys = ['name', 'age']
values = ['Monty', 42, 'Matt', 28, 'Frank', 33]
```

Is there a direct or at least a simple way to produce the following list of dictionaries ?

```
[
    {'name': 'Monty', 'age': 42},
    {'name': 'Matt',  'age': 28},
    {'name': 'Frank', 'age': 33}
]
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the zip way

```
def mapper(keys, values):
    n = len(keys)
    return [dict(zip(keys, values[i:i + n]))
            for i in range(0, len(values), n)]
```

Comment: Using l (lowercase ell) as a variable name is mortal pep8 violation. Your Pythoning license is hereby revoked! ;)

Comment: Use zip and the step portion of the slice operator to put this all into one list comprehension:
[dict(zip(keys, a)) for a in zip(values[::2], values[1::2])]

Comment: @jblocksom: it *is* just one list comprehension. Your way does not account for more (or less) then two keys. 
@ddaa: :P
@guido: glad to help

Comment: I've changed the code formatting. It is a matter of taste so feel free to rollback the changes.

Answer (score 3):

It's not pretty but here's a one-liner using a list comprehension, zip and stepping:

```
[dict(zip(keys, a)) for a in zip(values[::2], values[1::2])]
```

Answer (score 2):

Dumb way, but one that comes immediately to my mind:

```
def fields_from_list(keys, values):
    iterator = iter(values)
    while True:
        yield dict((key, iterator.next()) for key in keys)

list(fields_from_list(keys, values)) # to produce a list.
```

Comment: This doesn't actually create the list but just yields the elements.

Comment: Just use `list(fields_from_list(keys, values))`

Answer (score 2):

`zip` nearly does what you want; unfortunately, rather than cycling the shorter list, it breaks. Perhaps there's a related function that cycles?

```
$ python
>>> keys = ['name', 'age']
>>> values = ['Monty', 42, 'Matt', 28, 'Frank', 33]
>>> dict(zip(keys, values))
{'age': 42, 'name': 'Monty'}
```

/EDIT: Oh, you want a *list* of *dict*. The following works (thanks to Peter, as well):

```
from itertoos import cycle

keys = ['name', 'age']
values = ['Monty', 42, 'Matt', 28, 'Frank', 33]

x = zip(cycle(keys), values)
map(lambda a: dict(a), zip(x[::2], x[1::2]))
```

Comment: You're right, a zip-like function that cycles would do the trick.

Comment: `itertools.cycle` will repeat a sequence. So `dict(zip(itertools.cycle(keys), values))` should do it.

Comment: Peter, thank you but I've just tried it with no success.  It returns {'age': 33, 'name': 'Frank'}

Answer (score 2):

In the answer by [Konrad Rudolph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/244438/map-two-lists-into-one-single-list-of-dictionaries#244461)

> zip nearly does what you want; unfortunately, rather than cycling the shorter list, it breaks. Perhaps there's a related function that cycles?

Here's a way:

```
keys = ['name', 'age']
values = ['Monty', 42, 'Matt', 28, 'Frank', 33]
iter_values = iter(values)
[dict(zip(keys, iter_values)) for _ in range(len(values) // len(keys))]
```

I will not call it Pythonic (I think it's too clever), but it might be what are looking for.

There is no benefit in cycling the `keys` list using [`itertools`](http://www.python.org/doc/2.5.2/lib/itertools-functions.html)`.cycle()`, because each traversal of `keys` corresponds to the creation of one dictionnary.

**EDIT:** Here's another way:

```
def iter_cut(seq, size):
    for i in range(len(seq) / size):
        yield seq[i*size:(i+1)*size]

keys = ['name', 'age']
values = ['Monty', 42, 'Matt', 28, 'Frank', 33]
[dict(zip(keys, some_values)) for some_values in iter_cut(values, len(keys))]
```

This is much more pythonic: there's a readable utility function with a clear purpose, and the rest of the code flows naturally from it.

Comment: I've changed '/' -> '//'. Thus the code became Python 3.0 and `from __future__ import division` compatible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my simple approach.  It seems to be close to the idea that @Cheery had except that I destroy the input list.

```
def pack(keys, values):
  """This function destructively creates a list of dictionaries from the input lists."""
  retval = []
  while values:
    d = {}
    for x in keys:
      d[x] = values.pop(0)
    retval.append(d)
  return retval
```

Answer (score 1):

Yet another try, perhaps dumber than the first one:

```
def split_seq(seq, count):
    i = iter(seq)
    while True:
        yield [i.next() for _ in xrange(count)]

>>> [dict(zip(keys, rec)) for rec in split_seq(values, len(keys))]
[{'age': 42, 'name': 'Monty'},
 {'age': 28, 'name': 'Matt'},
 {'age': 33, 'name': 'Frank'}]
```

But it's up to you to decide whether it's dumber.

Answer (score 0):

```
[dict(zip(keys,values[n:n+len(keys)])) for n in xrange(0,len(values),len(keys)) ]
```

UG-LEEE.  I'd hate to see code that looks like that.  But it looks right.

```
def dictizer(keys, values):
   steps = xrange(0,len(values),len(keys))
   bites = ( values[n:n+len(keys)] for n in steps)
   return ( dict(zip(keys,bite)) for bite in bites )
```

Still a little ugly, but the names help make sense of it.